# How can I get test-results from an stb-tester ONE in CSV format

Tags: automated-testing, python, stb-tester

I'm implementing an automated testing system the [stb-tester ONE](https://stb-tester.com/stb-tester-one).  I've been able to run tests automatically using the REST API and now I'm implementing the Test Reporting module.

I want to be able to download the test results for a test-job in CSV format so I can feed it into my reporting system.  For each test I want Test run ID, test case name, start timestamp, duration, result (pass/fail/error), failure reason (that is, the exception that was raised or the assertion that failed).

Can you give me an example of how to do this from Python?

<sup>Disclaimer: I work on stb-tester and am an employee of stb-tester.com Ltd.  This is a sanitised version of a question we've previously received through other support channels published here in an effort to seed a stb-tester support community on stackexchange.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The stb-tester ONE provides an http REST API for retrieving test results which is documented [here](https://stb-tester.com/manual/rest-api).  In particular you will be interested in test-results endpoints:

- [/api/v1/results](https://stb-tester.com/manual/rest-api#get-list-of-test-results) - Retrieves test results based on a [filter query string](https://stb-tester.com/manual/user-interface-reference#results-view-filter)
- [/api/v1/jobs/(job_uid)/results](https://stb-tester.com/manual/rest-api#get-list-of-results-for-a-job)
   - Retrieves test results from a single test job

Here's an example of using these APIs with [Python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to get the results from a test job into a CSV file called `results.csv`:

```
stb_tester_one_hostname = "stb-tester-one-c03fd562ae33"
out_csv_filename = "results.csv"
job_uid = "/stb-tester-one-example/0a23/972"

import csv
import requests

# https://stb-tester.com/manual/rest-api#get-list-of-results-for-a-job
url = "http://{hostname}/api/v1/jobs/{job_uid}/results".format(
    hostname=stb_tester_one_hostname, job_uid=job_uid)
results = requests.get(url).json()

writer = csv.writer(open(out_csv_filename, "w"))
writer.writerow(["result_id", "job_uid", "result_url", "start_time",
                 "end_time", "test_pack_sha", "test_case", "result",
                 "failure_reason"])
for testrun in results:
    writer.writerow(
        testrun["result_id"],
        testrun["job_uid"],
        testrun["result_url"],
        testrun["start_time"],
        testrun["end_time"],
        testrun["test_pack_sha"],
        testrun["test_case"],
        testrun["result"],
        testrun["failure_reason"])
```

Disclaimer: I work on stb-tester and am an employee of stb-tester.com Ltd.